# Can I assign a header to separated strings in table

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file table that looks like this:

```
     A      B     C    D
1  1 2 3 -1 3 2  123  123
2  1 2 3 -1 3 2  123  123
3  1 2 3 -1 3 2  123  123
4  1 2 3 -1 3 2  123  123
...
```

I want to read this table like a CSV file with separators but this won't work because the length of the strings varies and the space between (i.e.) a string in C and D will sometimes have one space and sometimes a double space. The most important part is that all 3 numbers in A and B are assigned to their header like in a table. Just forcing a `sep= ' '` with `pd.read_csv` will lead to an error because I have fewer headers than new entries in the table.

Comment: When things are this ambiguous (Unknown number of spaces, mix of whitespace in-column and between-columns) it may be the case that you need to use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and custom code a solution

Comment: I was pretty worried about that. But I still wanted to try my luck. Thank you for the quick reply, I will keep trying!

Answer (score 1):

Since columns are separated by **2+** whitespace characters, so you can use `\s{2,}` as the separator to split by two or more whitespace characters:

```
df = pd.read_csv('YOUR FILE.csv', sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
       A       B    C    D
1  1 2 3  -1 3 2  123  123
2  1 2 3  -1 3 2  123  123
3  1 2 3  -1 3 2  123  123
4  1 2 3  -1 3 2  123  123

# Show the underlying values:
>>> df.to_numpy()
array([['1 2 3', '-1 3 2', 123, 123],
       ['1 2 3', '-1 3 2', 123, 123],
       ['1 2 3', '-1 3 2', 123, 123],
       ['1 2 3', '-1 3 2', 123, 123]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: As i said this changes unfortunately. This double whitespace is not the case everyhwere so forcing this as seperator would cause false associations here and there. For example between the numbers in A and B is only one whitespace, I will edit the original post to make this more clear.